# Mostrar un campo de un formulario con el uso de *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo este formulario que dependiendo si un usuario selecciona **SI** o **NO**. Mostrara otro campo del formulario.

```html
<select
    formControlName="condicion"
    placeholder="Selecciona"
    required
>
    <option value="SI">Sí</option>
    <option value="NO">No</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="condicion === 'SI' ">
    <textarea
        formControlName="descripcion"
        placeholder="Escriba aquí"
    ></textarea>
</div>
```

Pero cuando seleccion el **SI** no me muestra el textarea. Aquí coloco tambien como se esta armando el formulario en el typescript

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.makeForm();
}

makeForm(){ 
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      condicion: ['', Validators.required],
      descripcion: [''],
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para acceder al valor de un campo en reactive forms tienes que acceder desde `form`.

Así

```html
<select
    formControlName="condicion"
    placeholder="Selecciona"
    required
>
    <option value="SI">Sí</option>
    <option value="NO">No</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="form.get('condicion').value === 'SI' ">
    <textarea
        formControlName="descripcion"
        placeholder="Escriba aquí"
    ></textarea>
</div>
```

O así

```html
<div *ngIf="condicion.value === 'SI'">
    <textarea
        formControlName="descripcion"
        placeholder="Escriba aquí"
    ></textarea>
</div>
```

En tu ts

```
condicion: FormControl;
ngOnInit() {
  this.makeForm();
  condicion = this.form.get('condicion');
}
```

[Documentación](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model) formularios reactivos.